# unable to add IP address to Azure DB

Tags: ip, azure-sql-database, remote-access

I have a azure DB server, that I am using for about a year. From past couple of days, I am unable to connect to the server from outside (SQL Mgmt Studio). When I am trying to add allowed IP addresses, the page doesn't load properly. Here is screenshot.

[image]

However the application that uses the server is working fine. This is happening for a specific server only. I am able to do same operation for other server in my subscription.

It works neither in new portal nor through Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you try to set it using PowerShell, like [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings-powershell/) ?

Comment: "This is happening for a specific server only. I am able to do same operation for other server in my subscription "..Time to raise a ticket with CSS